# How to implement transactions in SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am new to SSIS. I am reading and trying to implement SSIS package using distribution transaction.

I have three SQL Instances SQL Instance 1 (source), SQL Instance 2 (destination 1), SQL Instance 3 (destination 2).

I have a customer table with one column FirstName Nvarchar(150) in source and destination 1 and First Name column length is Nvarchar(50) in destination 2.

My end goal is committing the record if insert is successful in destination 1 and 2. Below are my simple rules. I want to insert all records from source to destination 1 and destination 2

If the FirstName value in the source is less than or equal to 50
If the FirstName value in the source is greater than 50, then log the records to flat file. Not to sure on how to save failed records in flat file. Below is the Data Flow Task.

At present, either it will save all records or none. That means if any one record value is grater than 50, none of the records saving.
How can I understand this concept and implement the scenario?

[image]

Comment: add a conditional split before the multicast and test for len(firstName)<=50. Route those to a flat file destination. And send the rest into the multicast.

Comment: my mistake. reverse the signage like this... len(firstName)>50

Comment: Also before multicast but after the conditional split you might want to cast the nvarchar to len 50 in order to make the triangle warnings on the destination go away. I would use a derived column for this.

Comment: I am sorry  I should explain in detail when I post the question.
I am saving records in destination 1 and destination 2. It resides different SQL Instance. 
I want commit if the data is saved successfully saved in destination 1 and destination 2. 
I want to rollback if record is not saved successfully either in destination 1 or destination 2. 
One of the scenario is destination 1 is up and destination 2 is down. Then I don't want to save record in destination 1. 
OR
Record saved successfully in destination 1 but some reason failed when saving record in destination 2.

Comment: in that scenario your package would fail before loading any records. Test it out if you want, mess up one of the connection string. It should fail on preexecute.